# Editing printer driver settings in powershell V3

Tags: powershell, printing, settings, driver

I have 4 Windows 2008 R2 print servers each with ~800 printer objects and I manage them using a powershell script on one central windows machine.

I can easily create a new printer using the script but I'm looking for a way to change a couple advanced printer settings automatically after creation. This seems like an easy task if I'm using Windows 2012 or powershell V4, but I'm stuck with 2008 R2 and V3.

Is there any way I can adjust advanced driver settings (paper type, cut type, etc) in powershell V3?

I create the printer object like this:

```
$print = ([WMICLASS]"\\$server\ROOT\cimv2:Win32_Printer").createInstance()
$print.drivername = $driver_name
$print.PortName = $port_name
$print.DeviceID = $printer_name
$print.EnableBIDI = $false
$print.RawOnly = $true
$print.Put()
```